# Could not load file or assembly "ChilkatDotNet45.dll" or one of its dependencies, after deploying in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

My ASP.NET application works fine when run from Visual Studio, but after deploying in IIS, it throws an error like this:

> Could not load file or assembly "ChilkatDotNet45.dll" or one of its dependency. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

If I follow these steps:

- Visual Studio – Tools – Options – Projects and Solutions – Web Projects
- Select “Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects”

Then the project not run in Visual Studio and throws the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same Problem on the IIS Server you need to Install C++ RunTime.

For More Information see
http://cknotes.com/chilkat-net-assemblies-matching-visual-studio-versions-to-net-framework-versions-to-vc-runtime-versions/

Comment: @sebastian..installed C++ RunTime, but still same error

Comment: Do you have installed the correct version for your Framework as described in the Link above

Comment: You will want the vc++ runtime for the framework version that the chilkat dll uses, not necessarily the target version of your application. In my case, I found we had a .net 4.7.2 app that had a dependency on an older .net 4.5 chillkat dll. The 2013 runtime did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. First I installed chilkat-win64 and get error.
After I installed chilkat-win32 error gone.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/chilkat-win32
Hope it help